# Eclipse Mars weird behavior and look on Manjro

Tags: virtualbox, manjaro, eclipse

I installed Manjaro on VirtualBox to try it out as a replacement to my current distro.

So I installed Eclipse and started it up from the command line (i.e. `./eclipse`) and I can see the following: [image]

Why are Eclipse buttons are having a black background !

I also had another issue but its resolved now and I'm not sure why. When I open the `Preferences` menu, no matter what section I choose whether its Java, General, Web..etc, only the General main dialog is shown.

So I `chown -R root:root` the whole eclipse folder (as this solved a similar issue before on Ubuntu), opened eclipse, the same `Preferences` dialog behavior persists, but then I switched windows to do something else (after clicking on a preference section other than `General`, came back to eclipse after a short while, and found that the `Preferences` dialog issue is solved ! Has anyone seen anything like that ? Is it ok to `chown` the whole eclipse folder to `root` ? Why would this be a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to resolve the black buttons thing. I went to `Appearance` dialog available in the `Settings` application in **Manjaro**, and selected a different style other than `Menda` which was set then. Just click on a style and whole appearance of Eclipse will reflect the changes, then just click `Close` on the `Styles` dialogue when you are done.